# Failed to activate custom made systemd.service file

Tags: systemd, services, systemctl, systemd-unit

I created a bash script `scriptToCreateFilesWithSystemD.sh` to create a file inside a directory `dir4systemDfiles`
Both have read-write access for all and located in home directory

I added this code inside the bash file:

> [rajparayane@localhost ~]$ cat scriptToCreateFilesWithSystemD.sh
> #!/bin/bash
> touch /home/rajparayane/dir4systemDfiles/filecreated.$(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%I:%M:%S").txt

It creates files inside the dir `dir4systemDfiles` with date and time

when I tried running the bash file it worked fine

> [rajparayane@localhost ~]$ ./scriptToCreateFilesWithSystemD.sh
> [rajparayane@localhost ~]$ ll dir4systemDfiles/
> total 0
> -rw-rw-r--. 1 rajparayane rajparayane 0 Jan  2 20:42 filecreated.02-01-2023_08:42:34.txt

Then I created a `fileCreatorSystemD1.service` file to run this script automatically by placing it inside `/etc/systemd/system`

> [rajparayane@localhost system]$ sudo cat fileCreatorSystemD1.service
> [Service]
> ExecStart=/home/rajparayane/scriptToCreateFilesWithSystemD.sh

The `fileCreatorSystemD1.service` was automatically loaded in the `systemctl list-unit-files` list

Then I ran the `systemctl daemon-reload` command

The status of the `fileCreatorSystemD1.service`:

> [rajparayane@localhost system]$ sudo systemctl status fileCreatorSystemD1
> ● fileCreatorSystemD1.service
> Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/fileCreatorSystemD1.service; static; vendor preset>
> Active: inactive (dead)

Then I ran the command `sudo systemctl start fileCreatorSystemD1`

It started the service but now its status shows `Active: failed`

> [rajparayane@localhost system]$ sudo systemctl status fileCreatorSystemD1
> ● fileCreatorSystemD1.service
> Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/fileCreatorSystemD1.service; static; vendor preset>
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2023-01-02 20:27:05 IST; 2s ago
> Process: 4089 ExecStart=/home/rajparayane/scriptToCreateFilesWithSystemD.sh (code=exite>
> Main PID: 4089 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Also It didn't execute the bash file `scriptToCreateFilesWithSystemD` which was mentioned in the `fileCreatorSystemD1.service`

> sudo cat fileCreatorSystemD1.service
> [Service]
> ExecStart=/home/rajparayane/scriptToCreateFilesWithSystemD.sh

Comment: One possibility: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/583588/117549

Comment: And https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665036/117549

Comment: And https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/490707/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller  It worked !! Thank You. From your suggested link: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/665036/117549 I tried to move my program `scriptToCreateFilesWithSystemD.sh` from home to `/user/local/bin/` and ran the command `restorecon -Rv /usr/local/bin` which responded with `Relabeled /usr/local/bin/scriptToCreateFilesWithSystemD.sh from unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 to unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 `

Comment: @JeffSchaller can you explain in simple terms what is the meaning of this line `Relabeled /usr/local/bin/scriptToCreateFilesWithSystemD.sh from unconfined_u:object_r:user_home_t:s0 to unconfined_u:object_r:bin_t:s0 `

Comment: I'm happy to hear that my breadcrumbs led you to a solution (or work-around)! The simplest thing to do at this point would be to close this question as a duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/664811/117549, since that Answer solved this problem. I wasn't sure initially what the problem was; without more evidence in this question, it'd be hard to write a proper Answer.

Comment: Re: the `restorecon` "Relabeld..." message, I'd recommend checking the man page for `restorecon` as well as an introduction to SE Linux. If you're still confused, I'd recommend opening a new Question.